# photoeditorsdk force crop in photo editor

Tags: photoeditorsdk

I am trying to use force crop before the editor loads. I tried using the example given in the documentation, but it throws an error saying `Could not find control with identifier crop`.

Plus it doesn't work with the DesktopUI. It is only being invoked when I use the ReactUI.

Answer (score 0):

The identifier is `transform`:

```
forceControls: [
  {
    control: "transform",
    options: {
      ratios: [
        {
          identifier: 'imgly_transform_common_9-16', // custom crop
          defaultName: '9:16',
          ratio: 9 / 16,
          dimensions: new this.PhotoEditorSDK.Math.Vector2(720, 1280),
          selected: true
        },
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
editor: {
    controlsOptions: {
      transform: {
        ratios: [
          {
            name: 'your_custom_dimension_name',
            ratio: 3 / 1,
            defaultName: "3:1",
            dimensions: new PhotoEditorSDK.Math.Vector2(600, 200)
          }
        ],
        replaceRatios: false
      }
    }
  }
```

---

Add this code inside editor object, then it will work properly.